# Understanding newRV_inc vs newRV_noinc

Tags: perl, perlguts

In trying to deal with references at the C level I can't seem to figure out the difference (in practice) between `newRV_inc` and `newRV_noinc`. To that end I have mocked up this little `Inline::C` example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::Peek 'SvREFCNT';

my $arrayref_inc = make_arrayref_inc();
print "inc: ", SvREFCNT($arrayref_inc), "\n";

my $arrayref_noinc = make_arrayref_noinc();
print "noinc: ", SvREFCNT($arrayref_noinc), "\n";

use Inline C => <<'END_C';
SV* make_arrayref_inc () {
  AV * array = newAV();
  SV * arrayref = newRV_inc((SV *)array);

  return arrayref;
}

SV* make_arrayref_noinc () {
  AV * array = newAV();
  SV * arrayref = newRV_noinc((SV *)array);

  return arrayref;
}
END_C
```

gives:

```
inc: 1
noinc: 1
```

Can anyone help me understand why this code behaves this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `SvREFCNT($arrayref)` you're getting the reference count of the *arrayref*, not the *array* that it's referencing.  `newRV_inc` increments the reference count of `array`, and `newRV_noinc` doesn't.  But that doesn't make any difference to the reference count of `arrayref`.  (I don't think you can get at the refcount of the array referenced by an arrayref with Devel::Peek.)

Have you read the example in [perlguts: Reference Counts and Mortality](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Reference-Counts-and-Mortality)?

`AV* array = newAV()` creates a new array with a refcount of 1.  In `make_arrayref_inc`, `newRV_inc` increments that to 2 while creating a new SV (the arrayref) with a refcount of 1.  This causes a memory leak, because you don't decrement `array`'s refcount before exiting the function.  Perl thinks it has 2 references, but it really only has 1, so it will never be garbage collected until the interpreter shuts down.

That's why you normally use `newRV_noinc` in code that returns a reference to a newly created value.  It's more efficient than using `newRV_inc` and then `SvREFCNT_dec`.  You can think of `newRV_noinc` as transferring ownership of the AV from `array` to `arrayref`.

Comment: Thanks @cjm, that last paragraph finally is what I need to understand when to increment. Although I bet that in practice I will continue to use the "lowest number of increments that doesn't destroy the object" method that I have been using so far.